# How to call php session uid from subdomain and display output to www.domain.com

Tags: php, mysql, session

How to call php session uid from subdomain directory to main domain directory.

session uid created and work with below two files -

```
manage.domain.com/includes/function.php
manage.domain.com/init.php
```

full code -

```
    <?php
require $_SERVER['public_html'] . 'includes/functions.php';
require $_SERVER['public_html'] . 'init.php';

    if ($_SESSION['uid']) {
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT firstname,lastname FROM tblclients WHERE id=" . $_SESSION['uid'] . "");

    $data = mysql_fetch_array ($result);
  echo "<hr/><strong>Welcome Back</strong><br>";

    echo "<strong>{$data['firstname']}</strong> " ;
  echo "<strong>{$data['lastname']}</strong><br><br>" ;

    echo "<br><br><form method=post action=logout.php><input type=submit class=submitbutton value=Logout /></form>";

}

    else  {
  echo '<a href="/clients">Login</a> 
}
?>
```

Above code work perfect with main domain.  but it's not working with subdomain

Answer (score 0):

Put the following code on both your main domain and sub-domain just before session_start():

```
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.domain.com');
```

Notice the period before domain name. This will make session cookie available on all sub-domains.
But I would not recommend to do this due to some security thoughts.

Comment: but the page is secured with SSL, so then it's possible to hack?

Comment: It depends on how sessions are managed.  Imagine, you authenticated on sub-domain A, then go to sub-domain B. What happens when domain B sees the session with unexpected data inside?